# Profiler not working after upgrade from 1.8.0 to 1.8.1

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, profiler

I needed to find a chokepoint in my code, and while it worked in 1.8.0, after the upgrade to 1.8.1 the profiler only shows the table headers like this:

```
Memory usage: real: 35913728, emalloc: 34225312
Code Profiler   Time    Cnt Emalloc RealMem
```

I can't really find out why it is broken. I'm wondering if more poeple have this problem, since I haven't come across any solutions yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to un-comment the

```
#Varien_Profiler::enable();
```

From index.php.

Comment: Right. I'm stupid. I just didn't check that.. Thanks!